# Multiple variable assignment using 'read' works in bash v4.3.48 and does not in v4.4.7

Tags: bash, variables, newline, variable-assignment

I'm using two distros which use bash v4.3.48 and v4.4.7.

```
read VAR1 VAR2 <<< $(echo 0 ; echo 1)
echo $VAR2
```

For bash v4.3.48, the result of commands above is $VAR2 has value 1.
But, with bash 4.4.7, $VAR2 is null.

To get the same result, in 4.4.7, I must modify the script:

```
read VAR1 VAR2 <<< $(echo -n $(echo 0 ; echo 1) )
```

I don't know my (previous) script was wrong or there're changes in the newer bash.

Comment: The previous script certainly reads as wrong to me, or at least, relying on undefined behavior. `{ read var1; read var2; } <<<"$(echo 0; echo 1)"` is much better-defined. So is `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' var1 var2 < <(printf '%s\n' 0 1 && printf '\0')`. So are... well, *most* things not relying on unquoted expansion behaviors.

Comment: (btw, re: `var1` vs `VAR1`, see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html: all-caps variable names are used by the shell and OS components; names with lowercase characters are guaranteed not to have unintended side effects on shell or POSIX-specified-OS-component operation).

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for the tips! About, the first one, it's similar when I use read in a loop, but I don't ever think about using this way you mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the behavior when expanding `<<< $( )` has changed slightly. Normally, when `$( )` occurs without double-quotes around it, the result undergoes word splitting and wildcard expansion. But when it's after `<<<` it appears that early versions of `bash` skip the wildcard expansion part but do word-split it and then paste the result back together with spaces. You can see this by using `cat` instead of `read`:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.10(1)-release
$ cat <<< $(echo 0; echo 1)
0 1
$ cat <<< $(echo '*       *'; echo 1)
* * 1
```

Note that the extra spaces in '*       *' have vanished, and the line breaks between the two `echo`ed string have turned into spaces, but the wildcards didn't get expanded into a list of files. As a result, when you use `read VAR1 VAR2 <<< $(echo 0 ; echo 1)`, `read` receives "0 1" and puts those digits in the two variables.

On the other hand, newer versions of `bash` skip the word splitting as well:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release
$ cat <<< $(echo 0; echo 1)
0
1
$ cat <<< $(echo '*       *'; echo 1)
*       *
1
```

That means that when you use `read VAR1 VAR2 <<< $(echo 0 ; echo 1)`, the `read` command receives *two lines*: "0" and "1", but it only reads a single line ("0") and so only `$VAR1` gets a value.

Update: [Eric Renouf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143008/read-myfunc-behavior-differs-between-bash-4-2-and-4-4/46143582#46143582) spotted the change in the [release notes for bash-4.4-beta](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-10/msg00101.html):

> z.  Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the
>   documentation
>       has always said.

Comment: '....and so only $VAR1 gets a value.' . This can be adjusted by instructing `read` not to use newline as a delimiter (default behavior) using `read -d '' var1 var2`

Comment: ...though without a trailing NUL on the input, that `read` will exit with a nonzero exit status, which might be a situation that calls for some care in handling. In a lot of situations I prefer to just tack a `&& printf '\0'` onto the command generating the stream -- that way the exit status of `read` mirrors the exit status of the command generating its input.

Comment: This was a bug in `bash`; unquoted expansions were always documented as not undergoing word-splitting in a here string, but a regression introduced in 4.0(?) persisted in various forms until 4.3 and 4.4.

Comment: @chepner Interesting. But the bug has to be a lot older than that -- I see the same (word-split-and-paste) result under `bash` v3.2.57 and even v2.05b.0.

Comment: Yeah, I double-checked the 3.2 man page and notice it just says the expression is "expanded". I think, but don't have a copy readily available to check, that the man page started to become more specific about how the here string was expanded, but the code didn't follow suit until 4.3 and 4.4.