# read <<<$(myfunc) behavior differs between bash 4.2 and 4.4

Tags: bash

I have some code below to read an array from a list

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

function getlist {
    printf "%q/\n" "foo"
    printf "%q/\n" "bar"
}

IFS="$(printf ' \n\t')"
# IFS=" "

while read -r tmp; do
    echo "test"
    echo $tmp
done <<< $(getlist)
```

4.2 bash output

```
$ ./test.sh
test
foo/ bar/
```

4.4 output

```
$ ./test.sh
test
foo/
test
bar/
```

However, if I change IFS=" ", they behave the same as 4.4 (but actually the delimiter is \n, right?). Wonder what change has been made between these two versions

Comment: As an aside, better to use the POSIX-compliant `getlist() {` declaration syntax with no `function` preceding; `function` is like `let`, a backwards-compatibility vestige (for ksh, in this case) with no advantages over the compliant (and thus portable) alternative.

Comment: Also, `IFS=$' \n\t'` is much more efficient than running a command substitution with `printf`. (In ksh93, the shell doesn't actually fork for the substitution and just runs printf in the current shell -- but bash doesn't have that optimization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue isn't with `read` it's with your not quoting the herestring.  If you quote it you get the 4.4 results in both cases:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

function getlist {
    printf "%q/\n" "foo"
    printf "%q/\n" "bar"
}

IFS="$(printf ' \n\t')"
# IFS=" "

while read -r tmp; do
    echo "test"
    echo $tmp
done <<< "$(getlist)"
```

It's different in bash 4.4 because it fixed a deviation from the documentation as found [in the release notes](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-08/msg00123.html) in:

> z.  Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the documentation has always said.

Comment: Adding quote does make them the same. But still curious about several things. (1) why a quote matters? (2) how does not 4.4 need quote (3) why change IFS to " " works

Comment: @fushupinnanren, (1) double quotes suppress string-splitting and glob expansion. That's their *primary purpose* in shell -- nothing specific to `read` or heredocs -- after all. (2) as the docs said, 4.4 already suppresses string-splitting on herestrings, so if it's suppressed, it's suppressed even without the quotes. (3) an IFS value that doesn't contain any characters present in your string means that your string won't be split.

Comment: @fushupinnanren the problem was that bash was applying word splitting to the here-string so whatever `IFS` characters  were within the string would be removed and and basically replaced with a space, then `read` would see that result.  The quotes prevent the word splitting, and in bash 4.4 they fixed it so word splitting doesn't happen any more in that situation

Comment: Thanks. But why splitting makes the 'read' to read in the entire here-string? Isn't this opposite? Bear me if this is a naive question.

Comment: @fushupinnanren the problem is that the newlines are replaced with a space, so when the word splitting happens you lose your newlines so read sees both words only separated by a space and gets it all as a single line.  When there is no word splitting the line is left in tact, and the newlines are there for `read` to see

Comment: @fushupinnanren Compare the output of `cat <<< $(getlist)` under bash v4.2 and 4.4 to get a clearer idea what's going on. Also, see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177871/multiple-variable-assignment-using-read-works-in-bash-v4-3-48-and-does-not-in).